# The amount of people that currently have one product in their cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

How to display how many times a product has been added to cart Including all users.

```
$quoteCount = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->addFiledToFilter('product_id',123)->count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Load your product object and use below code to get Qty.

```
$cartItem = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($_product);
if ($cartItem) {
    return (int) $cartItem->getQty();
}
```